# How to remove style attribute in html using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, coding-style, attributes

I want to remove all style attribute in html tags using asp.net...

```
<div style="font-size: 12pt;">   Hello world  </div>
<div id=fll style="margin:19px auto;text-align:center">
```

I want the result like this:

```
<div>Hello world </div>
<div id=fll>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it server side, use some string replace or regex methods. If you want it client side you can do it with javascript or the jQuery library method [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Comment: I am using this, string expn =@"(?i)<(table|tr|td)(?:\s+(?:""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|[^""'>])*)?>";